# Problem updating photos in AD using LDAP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap

I have a certain structure in AD, and there is a site on which there is a user profile. All users are saved in AD. I wrote code that should update thumbnailPhoto in AD using LDAP, but an error occurs.

```
2023-10-09T10:23:35.148+03:00 ERROR 13892 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]. 
[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context 
with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: 
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: 
NameErr: DSID-03100288, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'OU=Пользователи,OU=Учетные записи,OU=Технологии надежности,DC=reliab,DC=tech'
]] with root cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID- 
03100288, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'OU=Пользователи,OU=Учетные записи,OU=Технологии надежности,DC=reliab,DC=tech']
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3285) ~[na:na]
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3206) ~[na:na]
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2997) ~[na:na]
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1505) ~[na:na]
at
```

The error indicates that the object supposedly does not exist in AD, but this is not so, below I attach all the code that I use.
Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/photo")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:update')")
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadPhoto(@ModelAttribute UploadPhotoDto request) {
    log.debug("uploading photo");
    var id = employeeService.uploadPhoto(request);
    return id == null ?
            ResponseEntity.internalServerError().build() :
            ResponseEntity.ok().body(id);
}
```

Service:

```
public UUID uploadPhoto(UploadPhotoDto request) {
    Employee employee = AuthUtil.getUser().getEmployee();
    updatePhotoInAD(request, employee.getEmail());
    try {
        employee.setPhoto(request.getFile().getBytes());
        return save(employee).getId();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while uploading photo", e);
        return null;
    }
}

private void updatePhotoInAD(UploadPhotoDto request, String email) {
    var dto = ldapAdapter.getOne(email);
    try {
        ldapAdapter.updatePhoto(dto.getDn(), request.getFile().getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error while uploading photo", e);
    }
}
```

Photo reqeust DTO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UploadPhotoDto {
private MultipartFile file;
}
```

Ldap adapter:

```
@Override
public LdapEmployeeDto getOne(String email) {
    log.debug("getting employee by email {}", email);
    return getByEmail(email);
}
private LdapEmployeeDto getByEmail(@Nonnull String email) {
    return findByEquals(ATTRIBUTE_PRINCIPAL_NAME, email)
            .stream()
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();
}
private List<LdapEmployeeDto> search(Filter filter) {
    List<LdapEmployeeDto> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        entities = template.search(EMPTY, filter.encode(), mapper);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.debug("Request to AD lasts {} milis", endTime - startTime);
    } catch (InvalidNameException e) {
        log.error("Error while getting " + filter.toString() + " {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (CommunicationException e) {
        log.error("Cannot connect to {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return entities;
}
public void updatePhoto(String userDn, byte[] photo) {
    template.modifyAttributes(userDn, new ModificationItem[]{
            new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new 
BasicAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_PHOTO, photo))
    });
}
private List<LdapEmployeeDto> findByEquals(String attribute, String value) {
    log.debug("searching by equals {}, {}", attribute, value);
    Filter filter = new EqualsFilter(attribute, value);
    return search(filter);
}
```

String utils:

```
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_DISTINGUISHED_NAME = "distinguishedName";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_CABINET_NUMBER = "physicaldeliveryofficename";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_PRINCIPAL_NAME = "userPrincipalName";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_PHONE_NUMBER = "telephonenumber";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_NAME = "displayName";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_CREATE_DATE = "whencreated";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_REPORTS = "directreports";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_DEPARTMENT = "department";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_GIVEN_NAME = "givenname";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_PHOTO = "thumbnailPhoto";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_TELEGRAM = "telegram";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_MANAGER = "manager";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_COMPANY = "company";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_TITLE = "title";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_SN = "sn";
public static final String ATTRIBUTE_CN = "cn";
@SneakyThrows
public static String getAttribute(String name, Attributes attributes) {
    Attribute attribute = attributes.get(name);
    if (attribute != null) {
        return attribute.get().toString();
    }
    log.warn("Cannot map empty attribute {}", name);
    return null;
}

@SneakyThrows
public static byte[] getPhotoAttribute(Attributes attributes) {
    Attribute attribute = attributes.get(ATTRIBUTE_PHOTO);
    if (attribute != null) {
        return (byte[]) attribute.get();
    }
    log.warn("Cannot map empty attribute {}", ATTRIBUTE_PHOTO);
    return null;
}

public static String getManagerNameAttribute(Attributes attributes) {
    String rawName = getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_MANAGER, attributes);
    return ofNullable(rawName)
            .map(StringUtil::extractManagerName)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Mapper:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LdapEmployeeAttributeMapper implements AttributesMapper<LdapEmployeeDto> {

@Override
public LdapEmployeeDto mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) {
    var dto = new LdapEmployeeDto();
    dto.setDn(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_DISTINGUISHED_NAME, attributes));
    dto.setPatronymic(getPatronymic(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_DISPLAY_NAME, attributes)));
    dto.setDepartmentName(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_DEPARTMENT, attributes));
    dto.setPhoneNumber(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_PHONE_NUMBER, attributes));
    dto.setStartDate(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_CREATE_DATE, attributes));
    dto.setEmail(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_PRINCIPAL_NAME, attributes));
    dto.setFirstName(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_GIVEN_NAME, attributes));
    dto.setCompanyName(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_COMPANY, attributes));
    dto.setTelegramId(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_TELEGRAM, attributes));
    dto.setBirthday(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_BIRTHDAY, attributes));
    dto.setPosition(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_TITLE, attributes));
    dto.setSimpleName(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_CN, attributes));
    dto.setLastName(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_SN, attributes));
    dto.setOfficeId(getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_CABINET_NUMBER, attributes));
    dto.setManagerName(getManagerNameAttribute(attributes));
    dto.setPhoto(getPhotoAttribute(attributes));
    return dto;
}
}
```

My connection to AD is working, because i can get employees, so i don't know why exception is throws.